# UITableView was hide by UINavigationController in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, autolayout

I create a UINavigationController in storyborad,and UINavigationController control a TabbarController
If tabbarcontroller have three viewcontroller,each viewcontroller has a tableview use autolayout,when app launching,The ViewController from TabbarController which first show,index 0 as usual,the tableview view is complete show on this viewcontroller,but switch another index viewcontroller,the tableview is uncomplete show,it is hide by navigationbar,the autolayout was not take effect
thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using a UITabBar instead of the UITabBarController. When you add the TableView make sure that you hover over the UINavigationBar so that the tableView should account for the nav bar and properly show the related content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deal with it by my self,If UITabbarController contains three UIViewControllers, each UIViewController have a UINavigationController